# struts - ¿Cómo implementar una entrada tipo s:select?

Tags: java, html, webservice, struts

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación basada en el framework `Struts`, y estoy implementando un formulario para el registro de un nuevo usuario. Dentro de los datos que usualmente se piden para dicho registro, está el campo **género**, del cual quiero implementar bajo la etiqueta `<s:select.../>`. Mi código que implementa la clase `ActionSupport` es el siguiente:

```
public class Controlador extends ActionSupport implements Preparable {

    /*Variados atributos*/
    public ArrayList<String> listGenero;

    public Controlador() throws Exception {  }

    public String registroCliente() {
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() {
        this.listGenero = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.listGenero.add("Masculino");
        this.listGenero.add("Femenino");
        return ActionSupport.SUCCESS;
    }

    @Override
    public void prepare() throws Exception {
        this.listGenero = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.listGenero.add("Masculino");
        this.listGenero.add("Femenino");
    }
}
```

El código select dentro del archivo jsp es el siguiente:

```
<s:select label="Su género" headerKey="-1" 
 headerValue="Desconocido" tooltip="Ingrese su género" 
 list="listGenero" name="usrGnro" />
```

Y el manejador de struts.xml tiene el siguiente código:

```
<action name="controlador" class="pe.com.pasteleria.controller.Controlador" method="registroCliente">
    <result name="success">RegistroUsuario.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Pero cuando intento ejecutar el archivo jsp, el servidor me lanza el siguiente error:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Pasteleria] threw exception [tag 'select', field 'list', name 'usrGnro': The requested list key 'listGenero' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]] with root cause
tag 'select', field 'list', name 'usrGnro': The requested list key 'listGenero' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]
at org.apache.struts2.components.Component.fieldError(Component.java:240)
at org.apache.struts2.components.Component.findValue(Component.java:361)
at org.apache.struts2.components.ListUIBean.evaluateExtraParams(ListUIBean.java:80)
at org.apache.struts2.components.Select.evaluateExtraParams(Select.java:105)
at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.evaluateParams(UIBean.java:864)
at org.apache.struts2.components.UIBean.end(UIBean.java:516)
at org.apache.struts2.views.jsp.ComponentTagSupport.doEndTag(ComponentTagSupport.java:42)
at org.apache.jsp.RegistroUsuario_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fselect_005f0(RegistroUsuario_jsp.java:518)
at org.apache.jsp.RegistroUsuario_jsp._jspx_meth_s_005fform_005f0(RegistroUsuario_jsp.java:319)
at org.apache.jsp.RegistroUsuario_jsp._jspService(RegistroUsuario_jsp.java:207)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher.doFilter(FilterDispatcher.java:426)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:314)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

¿Alguien me podría decir qué estoy haciendo mal? ¿O cómo puedo solucionar el asunto? Ya voy intentando variadas alternativas, pero sale el mismo error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si escribes

```
<s:select  list="listGenero" ... />
```

... Struts2 buscará en tu Action (en realidad en el "stack", pero bueno) un accesor ("getter") llamado `getListGenero()`. Eso vale no solo para el tag `select` sino para muchos otros.

Prueba agregar ese getter (y cambia el field a `protected` - no es necesario, pero es buena práctica).

De paso: en tu caso no hace falta crear y llenar esa lista en `prepare()`, habría bastado crearla en el constructor. No es que esté mal, pero me parece levemente preferible.